# Scene reconstruction from point clouds generated from ARKit4 LiDAR Scanner

Tags: python, ios, swift, arkit, lidar

I have followed the apple example to generate the point clouds.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Scan with LiDAR scanner and generate the point clouds
- Export point clouds in PLY format
- Then reconstruct the PLY model to make it a complete 3D model such that it looks like the real environment.
- For the reconstruction, I am using some python code. (Executing on Google CoLab Environment)
  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HXVOK53ac6BJHAFxdEVluhFr7UAZKtDV

I am able to achieve the final reconstructed model but the result I am getting is weird and not looks like the real environment.

Can anyone have an idea about scene reconstruction from point clouds with colored texture?